# How to create Windows Service using JRuby?

Tags: java, ruby, windows, service, jruby

I know we can create windows service using win32-service gem which is available in Ruby. How we can create a windows service in JRuby, is there any java-specific way which can be re-used ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's anything JRuby specific, but you should be able to use Java based service wrappers like '[Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/)'. It's used by a lot of OSS projects.

For more information, check the sample [integration](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/integrate-simple-win.html).

Comment: Is there anything that is comes with standard Java?

Comment: I don't think so. Java Service Wrapper is way to go.