# How to generate bytecode in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, jruby, bytecode, yarv

How can I generate byetcode from Ruby 1.9??

My intent is to generate bytecode not the source code and ship it along with my application package. I am aware of the JRuby approach but I am facing [certain issues there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013970/how-to-create-windows-service-using-jruby)

Answer (score 0):

Call BCEL library from JRuby. BCEL library is shipped with JDK.